# npm express.io install error on windows

Tags: node.js, express.io

I am trying to install express.io on windows to execute express.io framework examples but getting following error while installation. I have already installed node.js and npm using node.js windows installer.

```
C:\Users\amit>npm install express.io

> express.io@1.1.14 prepublish C:\Users\amit\express.io
> echo $(pwd) > /tmp/.pwd; ./node_modules/coffee-script/bin/coffee -o compiled/
-c lib/;

The system cannot find the path specified.
npm ERR! addLocalDirectory Could not pack C:\Users\amit\express.io to C:\Use
rs\amit\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\express.io\1.1.14\package.tgz
npm ERR! addLocal Could not install C:\Users\amit\express.io
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files (
x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "express.io"
npm ERR! node v0.12.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.11.3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! express.io@1.1.14 prepublish: `echo $(pwd) > /tmp/.pwd; ./node_modules/
coffee-script/bin/coffee -o compiled/ -c lib/;`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the express.io@1.1.14 prepublish script 'echo $(pwd) >  /tmp/.
pwd; ./node_modules/coffee-script/bin/coffee -o compiled/ -c lib/;'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the express.io package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     echo $(pwd) > /tmp/.pwd; ./node_modules/coffee-script/bin/coffee -o
compiled/ -c lib/;
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls express.io
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\amit\npm-debug.log
```

Comment: fwiw, i tried this. it installed successfully; in my case, i did not see either of the initial output messages you saw: neither the 'prepublish' one nor the 'echo $(pwd)' one. i used npm v 2.3.0 / node v0.11.15.

Comment: IMHO there's not much reason to use express.io anymore, socket.io is much easier to integrate with Express these days and express.io is seemingly unmaintained anyway.

Comment: I second **mscdex** on that you should look at socket.io as express.io is no longer maintained. Also, the error is screaming about the path: 
`C:\Users\amit\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\express.io\1.1.14\package.tgz` 
-> so checking your npm config worth a try: 
`npm config ls -l // and look for _cache_ settings`.